# Do jobs posters get feedback when we click X?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

If I see a job posting and dismiss it because of a particular feature (e.g. relocation, salary range, frameworks), does the company get any feedback from that? I know if I was posting a job as a company that I would want to know if/why people aren't interested.

Comment: There is currently no way for the user to give feedback on the why, though, is there? Not sure if the mere information that your ad has been dismissed X times would be very useful - some people might dismiss *everything* they have already seen, some only what doesn't work for them for some reason. For some, it could simply be the job's location, which is not something employers can do much about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't have an automated way of sharing how many users dismiss their jobs with our clients, but we *do* keep track of that data and can dig it up when clients ask for it.

We've tossed around the idea of adding a bit of UI asking for *why* a user dismissed a job, but we haven't settled on anything yet. The feature was designed with the user's experience as the main priority, first and foremost.